# error in addView() in change Fragment layout on orientation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, runtime

I am getting an error in `addView()`. Screen starts in portrait. I change it to landscape and now when I try to switch to portrait, it throws error.

(PORTRAIT Start) -> LANDSCAPE -> (PORTRAIT Exception)

chart ---- https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3784)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3637)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3582)
at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3558)
```

Fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;

public class EDA_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private Chart chart = null;
    private View fragmentRootContainer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(fragmentRootContainer == null) {
            fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, container, false);

            if (chart == null)
                chart = new Chart((LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart), EDA, 1023f, 1f);

        }
        return fragmentRootContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView();
        linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, false);

            LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            //((ViewGroup)lineChart.getParent()).removeView(lineChart);
            lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());


        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, false);

            LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            //((ViewGroup)lineChart.getParent()).removeView(lineChart);
            lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

------first--------

add this in AndroidManifest

```
android:name=".Activity.EDA_Activity"
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

------second----------

```
  in layout PORTRAIT add this -> android:orientation="vertical"

  in layout LANDSCAPE add this ->  android:orientation="horizontal"
```

--------third-----------

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getView();
    if(linearLayout != null)
        linearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup)chart.getChart().getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null)
            parentViewGroup.removeView(chart.getChart());

        fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, true);
        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup)chart.getChart().getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null)
            parentViewGroup.removeView(chart.getChart());

        fragmentRootContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, true);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exam, linearLayout, false);

        LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) fragmentRootContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        lineChart.addView(chart.getChart());
    }
}
```